# Error saving system information. Acceso denegado. Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, popup

Cada vez que intento guardar el proyecto o realizo algún cambio en el me aparece este molesto mensaje varias veces, los cambios en el proyecto en si se guardan, pero es muy molesto trabajar con esta interrupción constante.
He probado a ejecutar el programa en modo administrador, pero el problema persiste, también he ido a la ruta especificada (no fuera a ser que la carpeta o los archivos estuviesen ocultos, pero parece que ese tampoco es el problema).
Si alguien tiene alguna idea de que puede ser o donde puedo encontrar una solución lo agradecería :/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto parece un problema con los permisos de windows. Revisa los permisos que tiene ese directorio, quizás estén como 'solo lectura'

Comment: Pues si!, parece que era eso, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Bro que hiciste para resolver eso? Tengo el mismo problema